# JSSOR Slider Drag and Drop

Tags: jssor

Is it possible to be able to drag an Image from the slider (vertical orientation) to a pre-specified drop zone.

I have added an `OnDragStart` event to the images and it fires. But seems something is stopping it from dropping.

Comment: Please show some code demonstrating what you've tried and what isn't working.

Comment: I added OnDragstart event to each image in the slider.
The event fires.

Comment: In the Event ..
  var format = "Text";
                var textData = event.dataTransfer.getData(format);

textData is always null

Comment: Actually getting somewhere with this ..
jssor.slider.js

Line 2964
 if (_DragEnabled) {
                $Jssor$.$AddEvent(_SlidesContainer, _DownEvent, OnMouseDown);
               // $Jssor$.$AddEvent(_SlidesContainer, "dragstart", PreventDragStart);

Comment: Update your question rather than posting code in comments, please.